# Does router send STP Packets

Tags: router, spanning-tree

I have a doubt.
I have seen in real time simulation in the packet tracer , where the router sends STP packet to switch.
Does router really does that and can you explain since STP is for l2 domain only.

thank you in advance,
Regards,
Aps

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many routers can be configured as a bridge, with or without a virtual interface, so they run STP.  It is configurable, so you can turn it off if you want.